# How to show Tree Layout using JUNG but with tidier spacing and structure

Tags: java, graph, graph-visualization, graphml, jung2

I am trying to lay out some nodes in a Tree Layout using JUNG but would like to lay them out in a tidy spacing, similar to -

[Tidy tree layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nElmt.png)

I have downloaded the JUNG project from https://github.com/jrtom/jung and found examples of edu.uci.ics.jung.samples.TreeLayoutDemo and edu.uci.ics.jung.samples.GraphFromGraphMLDemo but have still struggled to achieve what I am after.

The GraphML file contents looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns  http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
   <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
      <node id="n0" />
      <node id="n1" />
      <node id="n2" />
      <node id="n3" />
      <node id="n4" />
      <node id="n5" />
      <node id="n6" />
      <node id="n7" />
      <node id="n8" />
      <node id="n9" />
      <node id="n10" />
      <edge source="n0" target="n2" />
      <edge source="n1" target="n2" />
      <edge source="n2" target="n3" />
      <edge source="n3" target="n5" />
      <edge source="n3" target="n4" />
      <edge source="n4" target="n6" />
      <edge source="n6" target="n5" />
      <edge source="n5" target="n7" />
      <edge source="n6" target="n8" />
      <edge source="n8" target="n7" />
      <edge source="n8" target="n9" />
      <edge source="n8" target="n10" />
   </graph>
</graphml>
```

I have been able to generate a Tree Layout.

```
private Supplier<MutableNetwork<Number, Number>> graphFactory;
private Supplier<Number> nodeFactory;
private Supplier<Number> edgeFactory;
private GraphMLReader<MutableNetwork<Number, Number>, Number, Number> gmlreader;

private void initializeTools() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    graphFactory =
            () -> NetworkBuilder.directed()
                    .allowsSelfLoops(true)
                    .allowsParallelEdges(true)
                    .build();
    nodeFactory =
            new Supplier<Number>() {
                int n = 0;

                public Number get() {
                    return n++;
                }
            };
    edgeFactory =
            new Supplier<Number>() {
                int n = 0;

                public Number get() {
                    return n++;
                }
            };
    gmlreader =
            new GraphMLReader<>(nodeFactory, edgeFactory);
}

private MutableNetwork<Number, Number> getGraph() {
    MutableNetwork<Number, Number> graph = null;

    String xml =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                    + "<graphml xmlns=\"http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
                    + "xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd\">"
                    + "   <graph id=\"G\" edgedefault=\"undirected\">\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n0\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n1\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n2\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n3\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n4\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n5\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n6\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n7\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n8\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n9\" />\n" +
                    "      <node id=\"n10\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n0\" target=\"n2\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n1\" target=\"n2\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n2\" target=\"n3\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n3\" target=\"n5\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n3\" target=\"n4\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n4\" target=\"n6\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n6\" target=\"n5\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n5\" target=\"n7\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n6\" target=\"n8\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n8\" target=\"n7\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n8\" target=\"n9\" />\n" +
                    "      <edge source=\"n8\" target=\"n10\" />\n" +
                    "   </graph>" +
                    "</graphml>";

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("temp.graphml"));
        writer.write(xml);
        writer.close();
        graph = graphFactory.get();
        gmlreader.load("temp.graphml", graph);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return graph;
}
```

Used as so -

```
    initializeTools();

    final MutableNetwork<Number, Number> graph = getGraph();

    // create a simple graph for the demo
    TreeLayoutAlgorithm<Number> layoutAlgorithm = new TreeLayoutAlgorithm<>();
    vv = new VisualizationViewer<>(graph, layoutAlgorithm, new Dimension(800, 800));
```

I can't get it to lay out quite how I'd expect or am trying for. This is how it looks - [default tree layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHAFp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of that particular 'tidier' tree layout:
[tidier tree](https://github.com/tomnelson/jungrapht-visualization/blob/master/jungrapht-visualization/src/main/java/org/jungrapht/visualization/layout/algorithms/TidierTreeLayoutAlgorithm.java)

You could probably retro-fit it to the version of jung you are using.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea about jungrapht-visualization. I'm going to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

JungraphtT worked perfectly! - [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XIss.png)

Thanks [@Tom Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9295106/tom-nelson)

Comment: Glad that worked. You may be able to use the edgePredicate setting to prevent the J1 rooted subtree from getting 'stolen' by node I2. The GraphView traversal follows outgoing edges but if you add an edgePredicate something like: (get outgoing edges)  "unless the edge target has more than one incoming edge and one of those incoming edges has a source that is a root of the tree". You may also like the SugiyamaLayoutAlgorithm for a graph like this.